# How do I generate Maildir/ and associated files in a user's home directory before they log in?

Tags: dovecot

Currently, a user's Maildir/ is not created for them until they log into the system for the first time. Is there a dovecot script I can run to make this happen before they log in to the machine? I know about /etc/skel but I'm not sure this is appropriate to use for this situation. I'd prefer to have dovect set up the correct files.

Comment: I did some looking around, and it appears Dovecot should automatically create the Maildir if it doesn't exist. How did you configure `mail_location`?

Comment: It does create it for me, but only after the user logs in. If I check the home directory immediately after setting up a new user with `adduser`, it's a blank directory.

Comment: It wouldn't be created until the user receives a message, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dovecot ships a `maildirmake` utility for use in scripts, and `doveadm mailbox` does work with the `-A` flag to affect all users. For the former, you need to pay attention to file ownership and permissions, for the latter you need to ensure that your *passdb* driver gets an appropriate user list *(or else you would create Maildirs for system users not intended to ever receive mail!)*.

I am not aware of a way to have the folders marked for autocreation also created on access via `doveadm`, but if its just the INBOX folder, either should work for you.

That being said, I believe **there is little reason to manually create folders**. If mail arrives, dovecot will create the destination mailbox (though, if sieve processes the mail, this may have to be explicitely specified). If a user logs in, all configured folders will be created according to their `autocreate` flag. Why would a user need to have these folders before accessing IMAP or receiving mail?

Comment: Thanks for response. I rsynced a user's mail box from another server to a new server. I wanted to copy the dirs in the rsync'd mailbox over to the corresponding dirs in the user's mail box. I ended up just creating a symlink to the rsync'd dir isntead of copying over the individual folders inside the mailbox. So you are right, I didn't need to do this.